# Access denied for creating records in public zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-route53

I am trying to setup some EC2 instances behind ALB and then create hosted zone for my domain and create Alias (A Type) record via Route53. My TF_user is having FullAccess on everything (I know that its not right but its just for learning purposes). I am getting Access denied only for this one step.

Code bellow:

```
# Create application load balancer

resource "aws_alb" "alb" {
  name = "ALB-Terraform"
  internal = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups = [ aws_security_group.ALB_sg.id ]
  ip_address_type = "ipv4"
  subnets = [ "subnet-X","subnet-Y","subnet-Z" ]

  tags = {
    environment = "Test"
  }
}

# Create hosted zone for Route 53 record

resource "aws_route53_zone" "test_zone" {
  name = "test.cloud"    
}

# Create Alias type record in Route 53 for my ALB

resource "aws_route53_record" "alb_dns" {
  zone_id = aws_alb.alb.zone_id
  name = "test.cloud"
  type = "A"

  alias {
    name = aws_alb.alb.dns_name
    zone_id = aws_route53_zone.test_zone
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}
```

Output from Terraform is:

```
Error: reading Route 53 Hosted Zone (zoneID): AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::0123456789:user/tf_user is not authorized to access this resource

│status code: 403,
```

I have tried using different accounts, importing existing zone, I have also tried to add and remove rights from the user.

Comment: You are using the wrong zone ID: `zone_id = aws_alb.alb.zone_id`. This should probably be `zone_id = aws_route53_zone.test_zone.zone_id`. This `name = "test.cloud"` should probably be something like `name = "alb.${aws_route53_zone.test_zone.name}"` and finally the `zone_id` in the `alias` block should be `zone_id = aws_alb.alb.zone_id`.

Comment: @MarkoE Thanks man, that really helped. I have spent good few hours troubleshooting this but as I am still learning it didn't cross my mind. Many thanks, you're the man!